# Need a regular expression to substitute left for right and right for left

Tags: php, css, regex

I have some css files that i need to use in RTL direction template. I need to convert all left to right and all right to left in these css files using php and regular expression.

For example: when it says "margin-left", it should be "margin-right" and vice versa.

Comment: why do it with php? use a text editor and replace it, it's easier

Comment: Because it needs to be replaced only for RTL users?

Comment: because there is a lot of css files to change, also i want to make a script to use it later. plus do you really have time to go through all left and right in 10 css files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simpler way to do it would be to:

```
$rtl = str_replace('left', '{left}', $css);
$rtl = str_replace('right', '{right}', $rtl);
$rtl = str_replace(array('{left}', '{right}'), array('right', 'left'), $rtl);
```

The bigger problem are these kinds of css:

```
margin: 0 5px 0 10px;
```

More bigger problem:

```
box-shadow: inset 3px 4px 32px black, 2px 3px 2px white
```

You should clarify on what kind of CSS might occur. I don't think you want to write a full fledged CSS parser

**EDIT:**
I replaced the `-left` to simply `left` and the same with right to also support the `position: absolute` positioning values.

Comment: it is not working, it converts right to left but not left to right. check this code:
  <?php

$file = '.logo {
  float: right;
  margin-left: 30px;
}';


$source = array('left', 'right');
$target= array('right', 'left');
$rtl = str_replace($source, $target, $file);
echo $rtl;


?>

Comment: I tought that if I gave the values as array like (left, right) -> (right, left) after switching every left to right, and continuing the second replace, it wont change those rights he created, but meh, he did, so every right became left, even those which were left to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This should to the trick

```
preg_replace_callback('/(.+)\-(left|right)/i', function($match) { return $match[1].'-'.($match[2] == 'left' ? 'right' : 'left'); }, $str);
```

Comment: if you made it with regular expression you should do a forward lookup for a : and another one for '/n', this way you wont replace values like background: url(picture-left.png). I didn't do it with my answer because 'left:' and 'left :' and 'left \t :' are all valid css

Comment: Yeah you're completely right, this would need some further work.